# Collapse Constraint Layout to SmallerView

Tags: android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have one layout. Now intend is when I come to this  view it should give me Expanded view but when I collapse it should  shrink to Smaller view

**What I have Tried**

I have tried CollapsingToolbar Layout but using this whenever I am scrolling view below Toolbar till Recycler view get hides get under the toolbar

[image: In below picture ConstraintLayout hide on scroll]

**What I Expect**

[image: I have View like this as in Expand Section Now if scroll down it should collapse as shown in Collapse column]

I tried customising the view but no luck

Any Help Appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that you want to take a `ConstraintLayout` and have that same `ConstraintLayout` shrink as a `RecyclerView` that is positioned below it moves up and grows as the `RecyclerView` moves down. Something like this:

[image]

Your thought to use `CoordinatorLayout` makes sense and what you are trying to accomplish may be something that [`CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior) can handle, but I will show a way to accomplish the above with an [`AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener).

Kris Larson has documented a similar method which is probably a more robust approach. You can find his **Collapsing-Image** project [here](https://github.com/klarson2/Collapsing-Image). He also has a good write up about this, but I can't seem to find it. If I run across it, I will post it here.

**MainActivity.java**
This is mostly boilerplate except for `onOffsetChanged()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
    private ConstraintLayout mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.shrinkingLayout);
        AppBarLayout appBar = findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            items.add("Item #" + i);
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mLayout.getLayoutParams();
        int newHeight = Math.max(mLayout.getMinHeight(), mLayout.getMaxHeight() + verticalOffset);
        if (newHeight != lp.height) {
            lp.height = newHeight;
            mLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }

    private static class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
        private List<String> mItems;

        RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items) {
            mItems = items;
        }

        @Override
        public @NonNull
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ItemViewHolder vh = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            String itemText = mItems.get(position);

            vh.mItemTextView.setText(itemText);
            int bgColor = (position % 2 == 0)
                ? android.R.color.holo_blue_light
                : android.R.color.holo_green_light;
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(
                holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(bgColor));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (mItems == null) ? 0 : mItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView mItemTextView;

            ItemViewHolder(View item) {
                super(item);
                mItemTextView = item.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }
        }

        private final static int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**
Also mostly boilerplate except for the `FrameLayout` specified within the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:expanded="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Toolbar Collapsing"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title="Toolbar"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
            <!--
            The following FrameLayout should remain a static maximum height. It is the ConstraintLayout
            that will change in size through program action. The layout "jitters" up and down
            if the contents of the CollapsingToolbarLayout is allowed to change size.

            The following two lines keeps the FrameLayout stationary so the RecyclerView can
            slide over it.
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"
            -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/shrinkingLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                    android:maxHeight="256dp"
                    android:minHeight="80dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:tint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_little_green_man" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Is that Image is below Toolbar ?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes, the image is below the toolbar.  I have updated the answer to show the toolbar explicitly.

Comment: @Cheticamp thank you! it's work charming. but one more question when `FrameLayout` heght set `match_parrrent` view its take jerking view. how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can create two `ConstraintLayout`. One for expanded and one for smaller layout that you want to display. After that you can switch between them in the following way in activity's OnCreate() method:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var isLargeLayout = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       val constraintSet1 = ConstraintSet()
       val constraintSet2 = ConstraintSet()

       constraintSet2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_expanded_layout)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_smaller_layout)

       val constraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.constraint_layout)
       constraintSet1.clone(constraintLayout)

       val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageview)

       imageView.setOnClickListener {

          TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
          if (isLargeLayout) {
            constraintSet1.applyTo(constraintLayout)
          } else {
            constraintSet2.applyTo(constraintLayout)
          }
          isLargeLayout = !isLargeLayout
       }
    }
}
```